# How to stream some logs over TCP from rsyslog in Docker?

Tags: debian, docker, syslog, rsyslog, docker-compose

I need a very simple thing (for an integration test of a larger system, orchestrated by `docker-compose`): to setup a `Debian` based `Docker` image with `rsyslog` inside, so that when it is run, `rsyslog` will emit some `syslog` messages over `TCP` to another machine (container). How do I do this?

I know `Dockerfile`, the question is about `rsyslog` configuration and how do I generate *some* syslog messages? Ideally if they could be predefined (to match them at the other end of the integration test).

I just tried adding the following line:

`*.* @@remote-machine`

at the end of `/etc/rsyslog.conf` inside my `Docker` image, but then apparently I get no message. Is the configuration wrong? Is the TCP port `514` assumed here? Or is there just no `syslog` message available when I run this container using `docker-compose`?

My `Dockerfile` looks like:

```
FROM debian:10.4

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get -y install rsyslog

# ... modify /etc/rsyslog.conf :
#   - append the *.* @@remote-machine line (see above)
#   - disable imklog which is causing errors

ENTRYPOINT ["/etc/init.d/rsyslog"]
CMD ["start"]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `logger` command to create arbitrary syslog messages. For example:

```
logger --server 172.17.0.2 --priority local7.info --tag TEST Sample log message
```